# Setting XMR-STAK as startup service in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cpu-mining, mining, linux, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 as VMWare Virtual Machine. Downloaded xmr-stak-portbin-linux.tar.gz.

I created a xmr.service file in /lib/systemd/system/

```
[Unit]
Description=xmr
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/aniket/xmr-stak.sh
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Ran following commands in terminal:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable xmr.service
sudo systemctl start xmr.service
sudo systemctl stop xmr.service
sudo systemctl restart xmr.service
```

Restarted computer.

After Ubuntu restarted, I did systemctl status xmr, and could see status as active.

But in supportxmr dashboard, I cannot see the worker. On manually running the .sh file, I can see the worker in the dashboard. What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely running into the same problem as me.
It seems that xmr-stak.sh only reads the config file if you start it manually.
Apply the following change:

```
ExecStart=/home/aniket/xmr-stak.sh -c YOURCONFIGFILELOCATION
```

After that do a systemctl daemon-reload and try it again - should work now with the correct config file.

Comment: Worked! The only problem I'm having is when I add * soft memlock 262144 and * hard memlock 262144 to /etc/security/limits.conf, ubuntu does not boot normally and shows low graphics message. How do you do it?